# Odd behaviour of `json.dumps` for \u0000 character

Tags: python, json, utf-8

When I execute `json.dumps("\u0000", ensure_ascii=False)` in python3, I expect the output to be a 3 character string, specifically, the `\u0000` character's representation to be enclosed in double-quotes. Here is what I get instead:

```
print(json.dumps("\u0000", ensure_ascii=False))
"\u0000"
```

Just to avoid any ambiguity related to my terminal

```
len(json.dumps("\u0000", ensure_ascii=False))
8
```

Which is quotes (2) + 4 zeros and \u (2) = 8 chars.

This seems inconsistent with the treatment of other UTF8 chars:

```
print(json.dumps("\u4e2d", ensure_ascii=False))
"中"
len(json.dumps("\u4e2d", ensure_ascii=False))
3
```

I am using:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.1
```

Is there something special about `\u0000`?

Comment: seems like this is true up to `"\u0019"`. EDIT: oopsy I didn't go through all the hex option, just 0000-00019 with all decimal, but the point stands - definitely happens with more then just `"\u0000"`

Comment: Certain characters are not allowed in JSON, `0x00` is one of them.

Comment: After some googling I got that "\u0000" is null character existing mostly for compatibility with some deprecated things. As it is null, I think output "\u0000" is most relevant since "null" itself is something that doesn't exists > no representation. See usage of null character https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-use-null-characters-in-character-arrays - it is just not supposed to be represented so does not have repr in utf table

Comment: @VladimirKolenov The character U+00 certainly **does** have a representation in UTF-8, like every Unicode codepoint. But in JSON, it's problematic to put a control character like this literally into a string, so it's escaped – like newlines, double quotes and tab characters.

Comment: @lenz okay, you are right, it has representation but this representation is not pretty-printable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), the following characters have to be escaped in a JSON string (Section 9):

> quotation  mark (U+0022), reverse solidus (U+005C), and the control characters U+0000 to U+001F.

There are short escape sequences like `\n` and `\\` for some of them, but there is none for the null character. The standard explicitly states that you need a six-character sequence to represent such a character.